# Find results with class name rather than text content

Tags: javascript

I’ve got the following code that allows me to find td columns with text content via a search box.  Instead of text content, I need to be able to find table columns that’s class equals the entered search box text.

How would I modify this code to be able to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".searchbox").on('keyup', function () {
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    search(this);
                }
                else {
                    $(".data").show();
                    $.each($(".searchbox"), function () {
                        if ($(this).val() != '') {
                            $(this).keyup();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            function search(ele) {
                var val = $(ele).val().toLowerCase() || '';
                if (val == '')
                    return;

                var dataclass = $(ele).attr('data-class');
                var SearchInText = '';
                $.each($(".data:visible"), function () {
                    SearchInText = $(this).find("td." + dataclass).text().toLowerCase();
                    if (SearchInText.indexOf(val) == -1)
                        $(this).hide();
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML markup?

Comment: `.data' class is applied on Table /TR/TD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hasClass, get all the td's class (`attr`) then check if the inputted string contains the characters of the td's class by using `includes`. If true then show the `closest` table otherwise hide.

But if you want to consider the **beginning of the string** use `startsWith` instead.

Now, to determine if no match has found based on the inputted text, you need to check the table length then compare it to the hidden ones.

Just an example as you did not include your HTML markup:

```js
$(".searchbox").on('keyup', function() {
  var textinput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var tbl_len = $('table').length;
  $("td").each(function() {
    var hasClass = $(this).attr("class");
    if (hasClass) {
      //var res = hasClass.includes(textinput);
      var res = hasClass.startsWith(textinput);
      if (res) {
        $(this).closest('table').show();
      } else {
        $(this).closest('table').hide();
      }
    }
    if ($('table:hidden').length === tbl_len) {
     $('#prompt').text('No Match Found.')
    }else{
    $('#prompt').text(' ')
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.ihave {
  background-color: red
}

.ihavenot {
  background-color: green
}

table{
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type ihave or ihavenot : <input type="text" class="searchbox" />
<br/>
<p id="prompt"></p>
<table border="1" class="ihave_tbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (ihave)</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ihave">North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ihave">Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" class="ihave_tbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (ihave)</th>
    <th>Country </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ihave">North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ihave">Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name (ihavenot)</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ihavenot">Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry this has taken so long to get back to.  I had to take care of a few other areas before returning to this code. Here is the modifications I need to make this work with new setup.  I need the search box to find full tables with a class name.  I need all tables that don't match to go away, and only show the tables with the matching class name.  That easy to do?

Comment: @KDJ Basically, its the same..I have updated the answer..you need to check the table element if it contains the class that is being inputted..if it has, then show, otherwise, hide it. also, i added that if the search input is blank or no value at all..display all the tables.

Comment: The only concern I have is that the text has to be fully typed out perfectly for it to show.  Is it an easy adjustmnet to display tables that contain the text as its typed in.  For instance, on keyup of "ihave" it will display all the tables.  Once you type the _, the "ihavenot" tables disappear, and the "ihave_tbl" tables remain.  Until something is typed that doesnt match.  So if I mispelled and put "ihave_tp", all the tables would disappear and display "no matches found"

Comment: ahh I told you wrong.  I just realized the scenerio that made me ask the question the way I did.  Shouldnt be much of a modification.  It does need to search for the table td class name.  But it only needs to show full tables that contain that td class name.  I'm so sorry for the confusion.  But my last comment does still apply that it needs to search as the word is typed and not only when it fully matches.

Comment: @KDJ check the updated answer..added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("td." + val)`  should be all

Answer (score 0):

It wont be a good idea to search class name on every keyup. Better to add a button and click event. Basic code looks something like this.

**HTML:**

```
<input id='searchbox'/><input type='button' id='btn' value='click'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='first'>aaa</td>
    <td class='second'>ddd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='first'>bbb</td>
    <td class='second'>eee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='first'>ccc</td>
    <td class='second'>fff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
<script>
         $("#btn").click(function () {
           var txt = $('#searchbox').val();
               if (txt != '') {
                   search(txt);
               }
           });

            function search(className) {
              // You can do anything here.. for ex. show()/hide() etc
               $('table tr').find("td." + className).addClass('highlight');
            }
</script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/imsangram/7ntrzsgc/